# RIO Delphi error

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe6

I have made several application where I use SOAP, but this one is giving me an error I haven't seen before.

Here is function in the WSDL that was created in Delphi.

```
function GetueSoapServerPortType(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): ueSoapServerPortType;


implementation
  uses System.SysUtils;

function GetueSoapServerPortType(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): ueSoapServerPortType;
const
  defWSDL = 'https://sandbox.usaepay.com/soap/gate/1412E031/usaepay.wsdl';
  defURL  = 'https://sandbox.usaepay.com/soap/gate/1412E031';
  defSvc  = 'usaepayService';
  defPrt  = 'ueSoapServerPort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as ueSoapServerPortType);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here is my function:

```
function TEWBModule1.ProcessCreditcard(card,Exp,cvv, Amount, name: String): Boolean;
var
  NewToken: usaepay.ueSecurityToken;
  tran: usaepay.TransactionRequestObject;
  response: usaepay.TransactionResponse;
  Wclient: usaepay.ueSoapServerPortType;
  CData: usaepay.CreditcardData;
  CDetails: usaepay.TransactionDetail;
  NewAmount: Double;
  RIO: TRIO;
begin
     try
        NewAmount := StrToFloat(Amount);

     NewToken := usaepay.ueSecurityToken.Create;
     NewToken := CreateToken(MasterTbl.FieldByName('Merchantnum').AsString, MasterTbl.FieldByName('Mlogin').AsString);

     tran := usaepay.TransactionRequestObject.Create;
     CData:= usaepay.CreditcardData.Create;
     CDetails:= usaepay.TransactionDetail.Create;
     CData.CardNumber := card;
     CData.CardExpiration := Exp;
     CData.CardCode := cvv;
     CDetails.Amount := NewAmount;
     CDetails.AllowPartialAuth := False;
     CDetails.Description := 'Web Payment';
     tran.Command := 'sale';

     Wclient := GetueSoapServerPortType(False,'');

     RIO := (Wclient as IRIOAccess).RIO;
     if RIO is THTTPRIO then
        begin
             THTTPRIO(RIO).HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout := 1000 * 30;
             THTTPRIO(RIO).HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout := 1000 * 15;
             THTTPRIO(RIO).HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 1000 * 60;
        end;

     response := usaepay.TransactionResponse.Create;

     response := Wclient.runTransaction(NewToken,tran);
     if response.ResultCode = 'A' then
        begin
             result := True;
        end
     else if response.ResultCode = 'D' then
          begin
               //Declined   response.error;
          end
     else
         begin
              // error response.error;
         end;

     finally
     NewToken.Free;
     tran.Free;
     Cdata.Free;
     CDetails.Free;
     response.Free;
     end;
end;
```

Here is where I get the error:

```
response := Wclient.runTransaction(NewToken,tran);
```

The error is:

> Project myapp.exe raised exception class ESOAPDomConvertError with message 'Conversion from class TRIO.QueryInterface$1093$ActRec to SOAP is not supported - SOAP classes must derive from TRemotable.

Could this be that the md5 token is wrong or this something else?

Here is how I create the token:

```
function TEWBModule1.CreateToken(Key, Pin: String): usaepay.ueSecurityToken;
var
  Token: usaepay.ueSecurityToken;
  PinH: usaepay.ueHash;
  PreHasValue: String;
begin
     Token := usaepay.ueSecurityToken.Create;
     Token.SourceKey := Key;
     Token.ClientIP := '127.0.0.1';

     PinH := usaepay.ueHash.Create;
     PinH.Seed := '5678';
     PinH.Type_ := 'md5';
     PreHasValue := Token.SourceKey + PinH.Seed + Pin;
     PinH.HashValue := MD5String(PreHasValue);

     Result := Token;
     Token.Free;
     PinH.Free;
end;

function TEWBModule1.MD5String(myStr: String): String;
var
  HashMessageDigest: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
     HashMessageDigest := nil;
     Try
       HashMessageDigest := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
       Result := IdGlobal.IndyLowerCase(HashMessageDigest.HashStringASHex(myStr));
     Finally
       HashMessageDigest.Free;
     End;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on the ProcessCreditcard function. I have added comments to lines I have added and to lines that should be deleted.

```
function TEWBModule1.ProcessCreditcard(card,Exp,cvv, Amount, name: String): Boolean;
var
  NewToken: usaepay.ueSecurityToken;
  tran: usaepay.TransactionRequestObject;
  response: usaepay.TransactionResponse;
  Wclient: usaepay.ueSoapServerPortType;
  CData: usaepay.CreditcardData;
  CDetails: usaepay.TransactionDetail;
  NewAmount: Double;
  RIO: TRIO;
begin
  NewToken := nil;  //New line
  tran := nil;  //New line
  Response := nil;  //New line
  try
    NewAmount := StrToFloat(Amount);

    //NewToken := usaepay.ueSecurityToken.Create;   //This line would result in a memory leak
    NewToken := CreateToken(MasterTbl.FieldByName('Merchantnum').AsString, MasterTbl.FieldByName('Mlogin').AsString);

    tran := usaepay.TransactionRequestObject.Create;
    tran.Command := 'sale';

    CData:= usaepay.CreditcardData.Create;
    tran.CreditCardData:=CData;  //New line
    CDetails:= usaepay.TransactionDetail.Create;
    tran.Details:=CDetails;  //New line

    CData.CardNumber := card;
    CData.CardExpiration := Exp;
    CData.CardCode := cvv;
    CDetails.Amount := NewAmount;
    CDetails.AllowPartialAuth := False;
    CDetails.Description := 'Web Payment';

    Wclient := GetueSoapServerPortType(False,'');

    RIO := (Wclient as IRIOAccess).RIO;
    if RIO is THTTPRIO then
    begin
      THTTPRIO(RIO).HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout := 1000 * 30;
      THTTPRIO(RIO).HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout := 1000 * 15;
      THTTPRIO(RIO).HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 1000 * 60;
    end;

    //response := usaepay.TransactionResponse.Create;   //This line would result in a memory leak
    response := Wclient.runTransaction(NewToken,tran);
    if response.ResultCode = 'A' then
    begin
      result := True;
    end
    else if response.ResultCode = 'D' then
    begin
      //Declined   response.error;
    end
    else
    begin
      // error response.error;
    end;

  finally
     NewToken.Free;
     tran.Free;
     //Cdata.Free;  //This object is destroyed by TransactionRequestObject
     //CDetails.Free;  //This object is destroyed by TransactionRequestObject
     response.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you take the time to show me. I have to go back and take a look at my other soap's and see if I do some unnecessary create. I'm a little confused when to Create and not.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can see some errors in CreateToken. It is a mistake to free the return value (token). I guess there is a line missing Token.PinHash:=PinH. Also it is a mistake to free PinH. Try something like this

```
function TEWBModule1.CreateToken(Key, Pin: String): usaepay.ueSecurityToken;
var
Token: usaepay.ueSecurityToken;
PinH: usaepay.ueHash;
PreHasValue: String;
begin
     Token := usaepay.ueSecurityToken.Create;
     Token.SourceKey := Key;
     Token.ClientIP := '127.0.0.1';

     PinH := usaepay.ueHash.Create;
     PinH.Seed := '5678';
     PinH.Type_ := 'md5';
     PreHasValue := Token.SourceKey + PinH.Seed + Pin;
     PinH.HashValue := MD5String(PreHasValue);
     Token.PinHash:=PinH;

     Result := Token;
end;
```

Comment: I only had VB as an example and I was confused when they declared Token.PinHash since I was not able to declare it.

Comment: In the part where I process the transaction I get an error when I free CData, CDetails I removed those. Should I free NewToken, tran and response?

Comment: CData and CDetails are sub objects of the TransactionRequest object, so they are destroyed by the TransactionRequestObject.  Yes, your method should destroy NewToken, tran and Response. There are other important changes shown in my post below.